# Xamarin Hot Start fails to provision iOS from second machine

Tags: xamarin.ios, app-store-connect, maui

I'm making a .Net MAUI app that I want to publish to iOS.

I've done so successfully from my primary PC, after enrolling into Apple dev program and generating all required keys and certificates. However now I'm trying to develop from my laptop and I cannot get Hot Start to run:

> There was an error while trying to automatically provision the project: 'Certificate: Apple Development: Created via API () already exists but cannot be found in the local Keychain. It may have been created on another development machine. Import the certificate and private key from that machine or revoke it and try again to automatically create a new one'

Now I can live with that for now. However I'm going to need my laptop tomorrow in order to publish the app to the App Store, because I don't have a Mac lying around at home.

The first time I got this error I was confused, because I was trying to authenticate with the exact same certificate I use on the other machine. Then I tried to create a second certificate pair on that machine and use that **however** it didn't work again. **Exact same** error to be precise, which is odd, because while I added the new certificate in Xamarin.AppleAcount settings, **the error contained the certificate key from my original cetrtificate** (the one that's working on the other machine).

I have not yet tried to revoke that one, but I'm reluctant to do so, because I don't want to risk breaking the setup that I have working only for it to fail again on my laptop.

Comment: *"I was trying to authenticate with the exact same certificate"* - [You mention key pair, so apologies if this is obvious.] Are you sure you have that **private key** on the second pc? I have no idea how this works on PC, but with Macs, its necessary to manually export the private key from the first Mac's keychain, import it on second Mac. (Just having the public certificate is not sufficient.) Re the mention of original certificate - I have a vague idea that either the project or the device is holding on to mention of the original. Maybe you can find that and clear it?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve VS requires me to provide public key, issuer and path to the certificate file, so I cannot workaround it. I've uploaded the private certificate file to a private github repo. The project is not at all concerned with certificates and the VS 2022 on my laptop is a fresh new installation (I've not even imported the settings from my PC yet)

Comment: The private github repo is somehow used by VS in the certification? Worst case, there is probably some hack way to clear the test device state in order to switch it between two different VS PCs, each with own certificate. What happens if you manually delete the app from device, then attach to 2nd PC that has its own certificate?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve the private repo is simply how I move the certificate file from one machine to another. That was a good idea, to remove the app, but unfortunately the outcome is the same.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve why would the certificate care for either machine? From what I understand it's purpose is to verify myself before the Apple API. Why would it care if I test on 1 device or many? And if I use multiple machines to develop on?

Comment: I agree; that is one essential question. The other is *where* is the conflict happening? Unless there is some weird dependence on info at Apple certificate server (because VS is having to work around some Apple dependence that assumed a Mac keychain was involved, and doesn't accord VS on PC the same level of trust? Grasping at straws here.), then its either on the device, or somewhere on the PC. (1) Re the device: Make sure no cached info: power-cycle the device after deleting app. (2) Re the PC: Maybe something cached in .csproj? Or in .obj, .bin, or hidden .vs of project?

Comment: In (2), I'm assuming giving 2nd PC its own certificate with private key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253230/discussion-between-alex-and-toolmakersteve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating different certificates and profiles is a solution, you can also import the certificate into another Mac or Windows machine. This requires you export the p12 file from Keychain in your first Mac.

Detailed Steps:
Open Keychain Access ->Login->Certificates>Expand the certificate so the associated private key is visible, right-click on the key and chose Export. (You will be prompted for a filename and a password) Transfer and save the file to another mac, then import the certificate:
Open Keychain Access ->File->Import Items->select the certificate that exported (enter the password).

If you want to import this certificate into your Windows machine:
Open VS->Tools->Options->Xamarin->Apple Accounts->select your team->View details->Import Certificate After that, you can download the provisioning profile and double-click the profile to install into your Mac (For Windows machine, you can open VS->Tools->Options->Xamarin->Apple Accounts->select your team->View details->Download all profiles) Then you can select the matching certificate and provisioning profile in Properties->iOS->Bundle Signing-> Manual Provisioning.

**In addition, you can also refer to this case which has the same error message [Xamarin Hot Restart: get "Certificate already exists but cannot be found in the local keychain"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1190364/xamarin-hot-restart-get-certificate-already-exists) and fixed this error without creating different certificates and profiles.**

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try all of that when I get the chance in the following days and I’ll get back to you.

Comment: You are welcome. Waiting for your feedback. @Alex

Comment: Exporting as .p12 file did the trick, thanks a lot. I had previously tried to import .cer files, which does not work. Also before importing .p12 my certificates were known to VS, but their status was "Not present in keychain", while after importing they are "Valid". I guess using the p12 files imported the private keys? Maybe it can be also done by manually downloading the certificates from Apple Developer and installing them on Windows, but I've not tried that one, since I wouldn't want to mess up my current configuration.